# Iterating over array of Objects -> Store Float Value of Property in New Array

Tags: arrays, processing

I'm trying to iterate over an array of new objects, isolate a value inside that object then store it in a new array so I can sort and calculate the median of the values.  I'm able to isolate the float value `m.BreakUp` but getting it into the `breakUp` array seems to be eluding me.  Any ideas on what type of array I need to create to accept the `mBreakUp` float values?

```java
// GLOBAL DATA
sourceType roster[];        // our database of Sources
int       nSources=0;       // number of Sources
float breakUp[];

void setup() {
  size(720,720, P3D);

  // load all data, with each record (i.e. text line) as a string
  String lines[]= loadStrings("MarriageSuccess-Table-S12.csv");

  nSources=lines.length-2; 

  roster=new sourceType[nSources];

  // create "sourceType" objects into database, with the line split by tabs
  //   ( "\t" == tab , "," == comma  , "\n" == carriage return/newline )
  for (int i=0; i<nSources; i++) {
    roster[i]=new sourceType(lines[i+1].split(","));
    println(i.mBreakUp);
  }

  // running into problem here
  for (sourceType i :roster){
    breakUp = append(breakUp,i.mBreakUp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tagging this post with the correct language may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured it out.

I was initializing the breakUp array incorrectly.  It's now working.

```
// GLOBAL DATA
sourceType roster[];            // our database of Sources
int       nSources=0;       // number of Sources
float[]   breakUp = new float[0];
```